# Allow only certain threads to execute in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading

I got two member functions for a class, say `foo1` and `foo2`.

`foo1` receives a string `label` and a `data` as inputs and calls `foo2`.

```
class MyClass {
public:
void foo1(int data, std::string label) {
  // do stuff
  foo2();
}
void foo2(void) {}
  
};
```

Now, I want to be able to create threads for parallel executions of `foo1`, but only threads of different `label`s can execute in parallel.

If a thread of `labelA` is called and another thread of the same label is still running, the first thread has to wait for the second thread to end its execution.

```
// t1 and t2 should run in parallel, t3 should wait for t1 to end
std::thread t1(foo1, "LabelA", 5);
std::thread t2(foo1, "LabelB", 8);
std::thread t3(foo1, "LabelA", 1);
```

Is this a known concurrency problem? I coudn't find a way to approach this problem, as it seems that a mutex is not enough in this case.

In summary, my question is: how to allow only certain "types of threads" to execute in parallel?

Comment: Your `std::thread` parameters do not match your `foo1()` parameters.

Comment: Might be a good idea to have a smart task scheduling mechanism so you don't wind up with all your threads blocked on label 1 tasks when there's tons of work to be done on labels 2..N.

Comment: *as it seems that a mutex is not enough in this case.* Why?

Comment: @RemyLebeau has the right answer. When you read it, try to remember: Mutexes are not for keeping different threads out of the same function or method at the same time. No harm ever comes _directly_ from different threads running in the same function. Mutexes are for keeping different threads from operating on the same _data_ at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mutex is exactly what you want. You just need 1 mutex per `label`, for instance in a `std::map` keyed by `label`. Then, `foo1()` can lock the `std::mutex` of the specified `label`, and unlock it when finished, eg:

```
std::map<std::string, std::mutex> locks;
     
class MyClass {
public:
    void foo1(int data, std::string label)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> g(locks[label]);
     
        // do stuff
        foo2();
    }
     
    void foo2()
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

```
// only one these "LabelA" threads should run in parallel with "LabelB" thread,
// the other "LabelA" thread should wait for the earlier "LabelA" thread to end

locks["LabelA"];
locks["LabelB"];

std::thread t1(&MyClass::foo1, &SomeMyClassObj, 5, "LabelA");
std::thread t2(&MyClass::foo1, &SomeMyClassObj, 8, "LabelB");
std::thread t3(&MyClass::foo1, &SomeMyClassObj, 1, "LabelA");

...
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/RPdWKF)